# Increasing PCIe Bandwidth Available to a 10 GbE NIC

Tags: linux, ethernet, redhat-enterprise-linux, pci-express

I am running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.0 (RHEL 8.0) on a Dell 7920 Rack. This machine has 8 GB of RAM. I do not have the option to add more RAM (its hardware configuration is locked down).

This machine also has a Myricom **10G-PCIE2-8B2-2S** 2-port 10 GbE NIC installed. I am not using jumbo frames (since the device that connects to this machine does not), so the MTU is set to 1500. This NIC supports a maximum RX ring buffer size of 512, and that is what the RX ring buffer size is set to (as seen in the output of **ethtool -g eth0**). This NIC only receives data (for packet capture from the connected device). This received traffic is always UDP.

From here on, I'll refer to the connected device as the **Device Under Test (DUT)**.

If I take the DUT out of the picture and instead connect an identically-configured Dell 7920 Rack running RHEL 8.0, **iperf3** yields sub-optimal results. What follows next is typical.

```
# Server Invocation
[root]# iperf3 -s -V --udp-counters-64bit

# Client Invocation
[root] # iperf3 -u -V -b 0 --udp-counters-64bit -t 30 -c 192.168.0.1

# Result
[  5]   0.00-30.04  sec  19.6 GBytes  5.61 Gbits/sec  0.004 ms  2002/14543900 (0.014%)  receiver
```

So, **~5.6 Gbps** is achieved, and there is some frame loss.

Frame loss is also occurring with the DUT connected. **Overcoming this frame loss is the goal of this post.**

(As a side note, when the DUT is out of the picture and I set both machines to an MTU of 9000 (i.e., jumbo frames), the **iperf3** throughput jumps to ~9.4 Gbps. Unfortunately, as I said, the DUT supports only an MTU of 1500.)

Since the MTU and RX ring buffer size are already set to their best available values, I've been looking elsewhere. Specifically, I've been looking at the PCIe bus.

The following was extracted from the output of **dmidecode**:

| Handle | Designation | Type | Current Usage | Length | ID | Bus Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x0900 | PCIe Slot 1 | x16 PCI Express 3 | In Use | Long | 1 | 0000:65:00.0 |
| 0x0901 | PCIe Slot 2 | x8 PCI Express 3 x16 | In Use | Long | 2 | 0000:b5:00.0 |
| 0x0902 | PCIe Slot 3 | x8 PCI Express 3 x16 | In Use | Long | 3 | 0000:b3:00.0 |
| 0x0903 | PCIe Slot 4 | x16 PCI Express 3 | Available | Long | 4 |  |
| 0x0904 | PCIe Slot 5 | x8 PCI Express 3 x16 | Available | Long | 5 |  |
| 0x0905 | PCIe Slot 6 | x8 PCI Express 3 x16 | In Use | Long | 6 | 0000:17:00.0 |
| 0x0906 | PCIe Slot 7 | x8 PCI Express 3 x16 | Available | Long | 7 |  |
| 0x0907 | PCIe Slot 8 | x16 PCI Express 3 | Available | Long | 8 |  |

I've also noticed the following appears in the output of **dmesg**:

```
32.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 5 GT/s x8 link at 0000:b2:02.0 (capable of 63.008 Gb/s with 8 GT/s x8 link)
16.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 2.5 GT/s x8 link at 0000:b6:02.0 (capable of 63.008 Gb/s with 8 GT/s x8 link)
16.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 2.5 GT/s x8 link at 0000:b6:04.0 (capable of 63.008 Gb/s with 8 GT/s x8 link)
```

Finally, here is the relevant portion of the output of **lspci -nnvv**

```
b7:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: MYRICOM Inc. Myri-10G Dual-Protocol NIC [14c1:0008] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: MYRICOM Inc. 10G-PCIE-8B [14c1:000a]
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 115
        NUMA node: 0
        Region 0: Memory at b8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Region 2: Memory at b9100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Expansion ROM at <ignored> [disabled]
        Capabilities: [44] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 00000000fee00378  Data: 0000
        Capabilities: [54] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
        Capabilities: [5c] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 4096 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
                        ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset+ SlotPowerLimit 0.000W
                DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported+
                        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+ FLReset-
                        MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 4096 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s, Exit Latency L0s unlimited
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk-
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk- DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range BCD, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
                         AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 65ms to 210ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
                         AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
                LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
                         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
                LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
                         EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
        Capabilities: [a0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=20 <?>
        Capabilities: [d0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=128 Masked-
                Vector table: BAR=2 offset=000f0000
                PBA: BAR=2 offset=000f9000
        Capabilities: [e0] Vital Product Data
                Product Name: 10G-PCIE2-8B2-2S
                Read-only fields:
                        [PN] Part number: 09-04244
                        [SN] Serial number: XXXXXX
                        [RV] Reserved: checksum good, 0 byte(s) reserved
                End
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
                UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt+ RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol+
                UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP+ FCP+ CmpltTO+ CmpltAbrt+ UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC+ UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
                CEMsk:  RxErr+ BadTLP+ BadDLLP+ Rollover+ Timeout+ NonFatalErr+
                AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap+ ECRCGenEn+ ECRCChkCap+ ECRCChkEn+
                        MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
                HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
        Capabilities: [1a8 v1] Device Serial Number XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
        Kernel driver in use: myri10ge
        Kernel modules: myri10ge

b8:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: MYRICOM Inc. Myri-10G Dual-Protocol NIC [14c1:0008] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: MYRICOM Inc. 10G-PCIE-8B [14c1:000a]
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 114
        NUMA node: 0
        Region 0: Memory at b7000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Region 2: Memory at b9000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Expansion ROM at <ignored> [disabled]
        Capabilities: [44] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 00000000fee00358  Data: 0000
        Capabilities: [54] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
        Capabilities: [5c] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 4096 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
                        ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset+ SlotPowerLimit 0.000W
                DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported+
                        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+ FLReset-
                        MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 4096 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s, Exit Latency L0s unlimited
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk-
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk- DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range BCD, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
                         AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 65ms to 210ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
                         AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
                LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
                         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
                LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
                         EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
        Capabilities: [a0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=20 <?>
        Capabilities: [d0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=128 Masked-
                Vector table: BAR=2 offset=000f0000
                PBA: BAR=2 offset=000f9000
        Capabilities: [e0] Vital Product Data
                Product Name: 10G-PCIE2-8B2-2S
                Read-only fields:
                        [PN] Part number: 09-04244
                        [SN] Serial number: XXXXXX
                        [RV] Reserved: checksum good, 0 byte(s) reserved
                End
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
                UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt+ RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol+
                UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP+ FCP+ CmpltTO+ CmpltAbrt+ UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC+ UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
                CEMsk:  RxErr+ BadTLP+ BadDLLP+ Rollover+ Timeout+ NonFatalErr+
                AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap+ ECRCGenEn+ ECRCChkCap+ ECRCChkEn+
                        MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
                HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
        Capabilities: [1a8 v1] Device Serial Number XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
        Kernel driver in use: myri10ge
        Kernel modules: myri10ge
```

### My Questions

1. How may I allocate more bandwidth to the PCIe slot the NIC is in?
2. Is there anything in the data above outside of the PCIe bus that would help me overcome the frame loss I'm experiencing?

Comment: PCIe is handled in bios (and hardware constraints), not the OS. Check in the bios for PCI link speed or PCI power management settings? Some motherboards have a max # of lanes which get "shared" between slots, so a slot marked 16 could get stepped down to x8 (doesn't look like that's happening, but maybe you can swap the card slots?)

Comment: The dmesg output looks like an issue with the card itself having issues. I would usually guess driver/firmware problems when hitting extremely high i/o. Do you still get packet loss if you limit the iperf speed? There are some troubleshooting steps here that might get you farther: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206197 . It's hard if you can't rule out hardware issues, but I would suggest contacting the manufacturer about the behavior

Comment: Regarding swapping card slots... This is a good point because it raises a separate issue I didn't mention in my post. There are two risers with 3 long PCIe slots each, for a total of 6 slots (I am unsure why dmidecode lists 8 slots). The NIC is in riser 1. All of the riser 1 slots are in use. But here's the interesting thing... If I put the card in a riser 2 slot, it is not seen. It must be getting power since it shows a link light when I connect it to the other machine I'm using. But other than that, there's no indication whatsoever that the card is "alive'. I'm unsure what to make of that...

Comment: Regarding frame loss if I limit the iperf3 speed... I do still get frame loss if I lower the iperf3 speed. It's not until I get down roughly under 1 Gbps that I experience no frame loss.

Comment: I did another quick search and found their PCI card guide. Seems like riser 2 is only for when you've got a second cpu installed(?) https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/precision-7920r-workstation/prec_7920r_om_pub/expansion-card-installation-guidelines?guid=guid-e19f08bf-68e9-45ac-8927-d2cccd315f4a&lang=en-us . They do have one example 10G card, and say it should go in an NDC slot specifically - though idk if that applies to your setup. The only other thing I can suggest is to check with Dell - I doubt you should be seeing those GT/s drops